# wpdb->update update the entire table instead of one row

Tags: wpdb, sql

I'm trying to use the `update` function of `wpdb`, like this:

```
$wpdb->update(
    'protocol_data_list',
    array( 'used' => 1 ),
    array( 'cod_protocollo' => $_POST['numero_protocollo'] ),
    array( '%d' ),
    array( '%d' ),
    array( '%s' )
);
```

But, this function update the entire table, instead of one row.
Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is `cod_protocollo`? is that a value that is unique for each row? also you seem to have an extra argument, update function only accepts 5 arguments.

Comment: You are right, I've added an extra argument. Now seems to work. `cod_protocollo` is unique for each row.